# $GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT, why not?

Tags: go

I've installed Go on my Linux machine in `/usr/local/go`, and intended to use `/usr/local/go/src` for development. However when I try this I get the following error:

```
$GOPATH must not be set to $GOROOT
```

Effectively as I understand it, this means you shouldn't use `/usr/local/go` for development. Why not?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because `/usr/local/go/src` already contains the code for the standard library, and you should keep your own code separate from that.

I know, other development tools would have no problem with that, but Go is a little more strict in some ways. It's probably the same philosophy that lies behind flagging unused variables or imports as errors - avoiding problems which may seem small at first, but can lead  to bigger headaches in the future.

Comment: i get this error because go binaray is under my gopath.

Comment: I get the philosophy, but, in many cases, a warning would be just fine. Especially with imports; many times I'm writing functions in and out of my code before it's ready, and do some builds in between just to check things. It's very annoying. With gcc, for example, I set -Werror when building for production, and that works perfectly.

Comment: This is super, super aggravating when you are just trying to USE a tool written in Go, and have no interest in a) how Go works, or b) development in Go.

Answer (score 18):

Add following lines to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export GOPATH="${HOME}/workspace"
export GOROOT="${HOME}/go"
export PATH="${GOPATH}/bin:${PATH}"
```

Then load the `~/.bashrc` file: `$ source .bashrc`

Comment: this works, since GOPATH is different than GOROOT and both are within your user's $HOME

Comment: @Geek, the `workspace` folder there is just a sample folder where you can add your Go projects.

Answer (score 11):

From `go help gopath`:

> GOPATH must be set to get, build and install packages outside the
>   standard Go tree.

Thus, GOROOT sets the location of **standard** library, and GOPATH is for **nonstandard** libraries. One library should not be at both locations at once.

Answer (score 6):

This directory may be where you `$GOROOT` is, but you can always check via `go env`, and this will list `GOROOT` as one of the environment variables:

```
$ go env 
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2.1/libexec" # <- its right here
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

So, your installation might have it in a different place, but either way you cannot make the same path for both `GOROOT` and `GOPATH`, the reason being is that your `GOPATH` also has a `src` folder, which houses the standard library:

```
@ /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2.1/libexec/src/pkg
± % ls                                                                    
archive   container errors    hash      log       path      strconv   text
bufio     crypto    expvar    html      math      reflect   strings   time
builtin   database  flag      image     mime      regexp    sync      unicode
bytes     debug     fmt       index     net       runtime   syscall   unsafe
```

The reason why you can't have them in the same place is because when you run `go install` it will look in both `GOROOT` and `GOPATH`, and it will see that all your imports like `fmt` and `os` are present in both `GOROOT` and `GOPATH`, and thus the poor go compiler will be confused and start shouting at you (which it did in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize it and it will work just fine without in the need to set GOPATH all over again, just run:

```
go mod init your-project-name
```

then you can use go get or run your go code with no issues at all

Comment: No, I'd say it's not a good answer. You should've mentioned why? It was asked 7 years ago; so please do explain so that people who might see this in the future can at least understand it. Talk about Go modules, etc. Also, format your answer correctly. The current state of the answer is not at all acceptable.